# How can I receive an AWS SNS notification in C#?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I know how to publish events to topics, but how about receiving them using the AWS SDK Client for c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "**AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient**", you will not be able to receive any notification. You're only limited to tasks that are related to publishing "**notifications**".
The SNS is designed as a delivery mechanism which requires a container to accept the notifications. Currently it supports:

1. Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)
2. Apple production
3. Apple development
4. Baidu Cloud Push for Android in China
5. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)
6. Microsoft MPNS for Windows Phone 7+
7. Microsoft WNS for Windows 8+ & Windows 8.1+

Hence, the .NET AWS SDK won't allow you to use the "**AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient**" to receive any notification directly. I'm guessing that's what you want. If that's the case, you need to use something like a AWS Simple Queue Service and create a SNS topic and use a SQS queue as the endpoint. Then you'll be able to **poll** the queue for messages.